# Angular dual drop downs first drop down repopulate after second dropdown value selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with two dropdowns.  The first one populates a list of Categories the second populates a list of Services after a category is selected.

I have the First list populating correctly and the services list populates with the associated services.  However, when I select the service desired from the services list, the Category list repopulates and looses the selected value.

An example is I choose from the Category list Account, the services list populates with two selections which is correct.  Now when I select the service I want, the First list reverts back to the original state when loading the page.

This is the html

```
 <select data-ng-model="vm.kioskCheckin.serviceId" data-ng-options="c.Name as c.Name for c in vm.categories"
                ng-change="vm.getServicesBC()"
                class="form-control input-lg" ng-required="true"
                id="category">
          <option value="">Choose Primary Reason for Visit</option>
        </select>
        <div class="v-Space10"></div>
        <select id="servicesDropDown" data-ng-model="vm.kioskCheckin.serviceId"
                data-ng-options="c.Name as c.Name for c in vm.servicesFiltered"
                ng-change="vm.setValues()"
                class="form-control input-lg invisible" ng-required="true">
          <option value="">Select Service...</option>
        </select>
```

Here is the code that populates the second dropdown (note when that page loads the second dropdown is hidden until the first dropdown has a selection)

```
 vm.getServicesBC = function () {
  var mySelectedCategory = $('#category').val().split("string:").pop();
  vm.servicesFiltered = getServicesByCategory(mySelectedCategory);
    vm.filteredServices = getServicesByCategory(vm.services);
    vm.filteredServices = [];
    $('#servicesDropDown').removeClass("invisible");
  };
```

Any suggestions or poiinters to what I may be missing?

Comment: when you do things like this it means you don't have an Angularjs approche " var mySelectedCategory = $('#category').val().split("string:").pop();"

Comment: $('#servicesDropDown').removeClass("invisible"); should be an ng-if

Comment: the value of the selected Category, comes back with "string:value" I am calling an existing function that returns an array of services based on the category, the category is compared to the database value.  if I use the full value it will not bring any values back.

Comment: I understand the issue now and you are right, see the changes I posted as an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was using the same model which would over write or cause the Category drop down to repopulate.

Here is the new html

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin: 25px 0 50px;">
        <select data-ng-model="vm.selectedCategory" data-ng-options="c.Name as c.Name for c in vm.categories"
                ng-change="vm.getServicesBC()"
                class="form-control input-lg" ng-required="true"
                id="category">
          <option value="">Choose Primary Reason for Visit</option>
        </select>
        <div class="v-Space10"></div>
        <select id="servicesDropDown" data-ng-model="vm.kioskCheckin.serviceId"
                data-ng-options="s.ServiceId as s.DisplayName for s in vm.filteredServices"
                class="form-control input-lg invisible" ng-required="true">
          <option value="">Select Service...</option>
        </select>
```

The new js code is here

```
vm.getServicesBC = function () {
  vm.filteredServices = getServicesByCategory(vm.selectedCategory);
    $('#servicesDropDown').removeClass("invisible");
  };
```